# Dropdown-menu-right in Navbar extends right side margin on IE11

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When building the navigation bar in Bootstrap 4.1.3, the dropdown on the right is using the .dropdown-menu-right class in order to keep it from clipping on the right side of the browser.  In IE10+, it is pushing a further margin on the right side when the dropdown is expanded (see example here) (Navbar-brand has been removed due to NDA with the client)

[image: IE 11]

[image: Chrome]

```css
        .topnav{
     padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
    }
    .navbar {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        max-height: 80px !important;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        line-height: 57px;
        font-size: 17px;
        height: 110px;
        max-height: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .search-nav {
        z-index: 1;
        background: inherit;
        margin-top: -45px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color:#77C044;
        float: right;
    }
    /*.navbar-nav.topnav-badges > li > a {
        line-height: 27px;
        height: 37px;
    }*/
    .navbar-nav.bottomnav {
        flex-direction: row;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-nav.bottomnav > li > a {
        line-height: 37px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #77C044;
        border-color: #77C044;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .dropdown:hover > dropdown-menu {
        display: flex;
        margin: -0.125rem 0 0;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }
    .dropdown-menu-right {
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1215px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        height: 40px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:1215px) {
    .container {
        margin-top: 80px;
    }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .container {
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .search-nav {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    }
    .dropup > .dropdown-menu {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .dropdown {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu a::after {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        position: absolute;
        right: 6px;
        top: .8em;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-left: .1rem;
        margin-right: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        color: #254609;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #254609;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        color: #254609;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #254609;
    }
    .navbar-default .topnav-badges > li > a:hover, .topnav-badges > li > a:focus {
        color: #254609;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    .navbar-power-grid {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-brand-left, .navbar-environment-label {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        float: left;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-environment-label {
        font-size: 12px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .user-name, .user-name a {
        color: #fff;
    }
    .user-name span {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .user-name {
        line-height: 28px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        background: #2e557c;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        background-color: #77C044;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #423e37;
    }
    .open .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        background-clip: padding-box;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #77C044;
     border-radius: 0;
     box-shadow: 0;
        display: none;
        float: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        list-style: outside none none;
        margin: 0;
        min-width: 160px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        top: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        z-index: 3;
        position: relative;
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li > a  {
        clear: both;
        color: #423e37;
        display: block;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: normal !important;
        padding: 7px 20px;
        margin: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
        color: #555;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #423e37;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        font-weight: 700;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active >      a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #423e37;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        outline: 0;
    }
    .dropdown-menu-right {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .dropdown-header {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #fff;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
        <nav class="nav navbar-nav topnav navbar-expand-lg navbar-default align-item-center d-none d-md-flex" style="margin-bottom: 0;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:0;">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
          <li class="nav-item left-nav"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Files  </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item left-nav"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Rolodex</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item left-nav"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Escrow Accounting</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item left-nav"> <a href="#" class="nav-link">Back Office</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class ="navbar-nav ml-sm-auto">
            <ul class="navbar-nav topnav-badges flex-row">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge">42</span><span class="d-md-none">Calendar</span></a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge">42</span><span class="d-md-none">Messages</span></a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge">42</span><span class="d-md-none">Notifications</span></a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown nav-item"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="caret"></span><span class="d-md-none">Account</span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Change Password</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item h-100"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-sm-auto search-nav">
        <div class="navbar-nav form-inline search-dropdown">
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-default search-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-size: 10pt;"> All Files <span class="caret"></span> </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Location</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Seller Name</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">File No.</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Lookup No.</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Policy No.</a> 
          </div>                  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-expand-lg navbar-default d-md-none fixed-top" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
      <div class="navbar-brand mx-auto"> <a class="text-center" href="index.html"><img src="../images/logo-e-closing-dt.png" alt="E-Closing DT"></a> </div>
      <div class="mx-auto">
        <div class="navbar-nav form-inline search-dropdown ">
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> All Files <span class="caret"></span> </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Location</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Seller Name</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">File No.</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #AEAEAE;">Lookup No.</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Policy No.</a> </div>
              
              <!-- /btn-group --> 
            </div>
            <!-- /input-group --> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.  Bootstrap.css was slightly modified and was interacting with the margins.  After fixing that, the media queries were causing some other odd margins.  Cleaned up the media queries and it works now in IE11 and Edge. So for any junior DEVs searching this odd issue, check your media queries.